# How common is ellipting '(that/which has) to do'?

Tags: grammar, verbs, ellipses, construction, have

I am wondering how often the structure 'that has to do' is reduced to just 'to do', and what style marker it carries in such a case.

Let's see:

> '...and that's how you know how much to pay for your gas and
> electricity –   but the National Grid already gets paid through our
> income taxes via the government.'
>
> Again that is not true: you do not pay for the National Grid through
> your income taxes, although the government *does* invest money in the
> energy sector, some of which may be going towards certain
> infrastructure around ***the UK to do*** with energy –   but the vast
> majority of National Grid's infrastructure is paid by way of bills
> that come to you via your energy companies. So part of your energy
> bill is made up of the consumption... the vast majority of it; but
> part of it every year is also going towards the National Grid which is
> the distribution Network. That is how it is paid ... not through your
> income taxes.

Source: a Youtube video, 'Gas and Electricity are NOT Free!' by
Daniel ShenSmith, a Barrister of England and Wales ('BlackBeltBarrister')

Comment: Some word is missing around "a spending". If the subject

Comment: Expanding "to do" into "that has to do" would transform the style of this selection from unreadable to unreadable.

Comment: "to do with" is commonly used a phrase in its own right, meaning "related to". (This may be a British thing.)

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Where does this come from, please? Quotations must be [cited and referenced correctly](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) (not least so they can be verified against the source). Please [edit] to include a link. Thanks.

Comment: @Lambie: I don't think there's a word missing there, it's just terribly style: by "the government does have a spending on X" they mean "the government does spend money on X"...

Comment: @psmears Well, it's gone now, isn't it?

Comment: @Lambie: Apparently so. Probably for the best, as well :)

Comment: I think it's misleading to claim there's a process of "ellipting" going on here. Just because it's *possible* to insert ***that has, that is, which has, which is*** at a particular position in an utterance doesn't imply that it was "in principle" present in the first place, and has been removed. I'd say ***adding*** something there is the "optional" process, not ***removing*** something (that was never there anyway).

Comment: @BrianDonovan Are you suggesting that Daniel ShenSmith, a Barrister of England and Wales, cannot speak proper English? At least, in his Youtube video 'Gas and Electricity are NOT Free!' ?

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to rule out a plethora of false positives in a Google ngram analysis.

A raw Google search for "Book to do with" - "book having to do with" (note that this is an alternative possible deletion) yields a claimed 15½ million hits, but further inspection makes this very specious. My own impression is that 'a Y to do with X' meaning 'a Y on the subject of X' or more generally 'a Y concerning X' is nevertheless idiomatic, but see below for register restrictions.

Of the results shown, about half have 'to do with' = 'about', as required, while the rest are 'to do with' = 'to be done with (the kids / dad / ...)'. All are in an informal, mostly very informal, register.

I'd say that 'have to do with' (which M-W lists, while [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-do-with) defines the string minus the verb but offers relevant examples only with 'have' or in one case 'be/is/**are**')

> **to do with** ...
>
> concerning; related to
>
> examples
>
> ... [false positives] ...
>
> - *It was very strictly controlled and had a lot to do with quota.* The Guardian (2016)
> - *He sees the mindset as having to do with the insular nature of police culture.* The Guardian (2018)
> - *The vitality of his films has something to do with mortality.* The Guardian (2018)

is less informal than the modifier usage (?'a book to do with quantum mechanics').

Comment: Really, ngrams? Harrumph.

Comment: Good point about your last three examples being far less informal than OP's cited example (which I was almost going to comment is a bit "slangy", but I certainly wouldn't think that about the examples from *The Guardian*).